# Shell Script - Check whether a single character input is uppercase or lowercase or special character

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

This is my code i have written. I need a simple code using if elif to check whether the character read is an uppercase,lowercase or a special symbol.

```
echo "enter a char"
read c

if [[ $c == [A-Z] ]];
then
    echo "upper"
elif [[ $c == [a-z] ]];
then
    echo "lower"
else 
    echo "Digit or special symbols!"
fi
```

The following is the output I received after inputting characters

```
enter a char
A
upper

enter a char
a
Digit or special symbols!

aravind@bionic-beaver:~/Desktop$ ./1.sh
enter a char
1
Digit or special symbols!
```

Comment: Your script works for me as written (i.e., it correctly identifies `A` as uppercase, `a` as lowercase, and `1` as a digit or special symbol).

Comment: Wow..But how??  Are you sure you copied the same lines of code without any modification?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code without modification into `/tmp/ex`, then ran `bash /tmp/ex`

Comment: Regardless of the fact that the locale setting will change the behaviour here, I do wonder how it's possible that `a` wouldn't be matched by `[a-z]`, since it's listed as one of the endpoints. Unless you have extra spaces or other characters there, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular expression tests:

```
read -p "Type a character" c
if [[ "$c" =~ [a-z] ]]; then
    echo "lowercase"
elif [[ "$c" =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
    echo "uppercase"
else
    echo "Non-alphabetic"
fi
```

Comment: Anyway to implement the same using checking the ascii ranges like 65-90 for upper case and 97-122 for lowercase? or can you help with the same code itself as it doesnt validate the lowercase characters.

Comment: Not with regular expressions, but you could be able to convert the character to an ASCII code and do a numerical comparison if you _really_ want to.  That's beyond the scope of the original question however.

Comment: **can you help me with the same code itself as it doesnt validate only the lowercase characters.? (without using regular expression)**

Comment: It says "lowercase" when I enter `` or `ABCd`. And Non-alphabetic for `α`

Comment: I imagine if you wanted to test for Greek casedness you could add e. g. `elif [[ "$c" =~ [α-ω] ]]; then`.  Entering `ABCd` matches for lowercase because of the `d` (and you did not follow the instruction of 'Type a character' - sanity-checking inputs was beyond the scope of this question).   I'd have to do a deeper dive to see why  is "lower case".

Answer (score 6):

Unless you empty `$IFS` and add the `-r` option, [`read` reads a line of input in a very special way](/q/209123).

For instance, if the user enters `" \x "`, with the default value of `$IFS`, `$c` will contain `x`, not what the user entered.

Also `[a-z]` doesn't match lower case letters, it matches whatever sorts between `a` and `z` in the locale (with some variation in behaviour between shell. For instance, with `bash`, in many locales, that includes the English letters between A and Y). It could even match sequences of characters in some locales and some tools.

Here, you'd probably want:

```
printf >&2 'Please enter a character: '
IFS= read -r c
case $c in
  ([[:lower:]]) echo lowercase letter;;
  ([[:upper:]]) echo uppercase letter;;
  ([[:alpha:]]) echo neither lower nor uppercase letter;;
  ([[:digit:]]) echo decimal digit;;
  (?) echo any other single character;;
  ("") echo nothing;;
  (*) echo anything else;;
esac
```

(that syntax being POSIX `sh` syntax, you don't even need to install `bash`).

If you wanted to limit it to the English letters (letters from the latin script without diacritics), you'd need to either name them individually:

```
([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]) echo English lowercase letter;;
```

Or fix the locale to C with `export LC_ALL=C` after the `read` and before the `case` statement, but then the `(?)` test would be invalid as it could incorrectly interpret some character as sequence of characters. For instance a UTF-8 `é` would be seen as two characters in the C locale.

Comment: Well, there's also `shopt -s globasciiranges` in Bash, but of course it still doesn't make `[a-z]` match an `ä`.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to wrap the variables in quotes - if you are testing a regular expression as a string, for example, you could enter the following:

```
echo "enter a US state name"
read var_1

if [[ "$var_1" =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
    echo "contains a capital letter"
elif [[ "$var_1" =~ [a-z] ]]; then
    echo "contains lower case letters"
else
    echo "contains special characters or numbers"
fi
```

Comment: Can you please explain where does the `=~` come from? I was unable to find a reference to it in the man page for test (`man test`)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
while read -r line; do
    [[ "${line:0:1}" =~ [[:upper:]] ]] && echo "Started with upper: $line" || echo "$line";
done</path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried in Python and it worked fine too

```
#!/usr/bin/python
input=raw_input("enter the user input")
k=input.isalpha()
alph_out=str(k)
if alph_out == "True":
    print "{0} is alphabet".format(input)
    upper_lower=input.isupper()
    up_lo_deci=str(upper_lower)
    if up_lo_deci == "True":
        print "{0} is Capital letter".format(input)
    elif up_lo_deci == "False":
        print "{0} is lower letter".format(input)
elif alph_out == "False":
    print "{0} is digit or symbole".format(input)
```

output

praveen:~/

```
t1$ python u.py 
enter the user input
10
10 is digit or symbole


ter the user input
P
P is alphabet
P is Capital letter

aveen@praveen:~/t1$ python u.py 
enter the user input
e
e is alphabet
e is lower letter
```